# Link one model more than once

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.2, cakephp-model

I have a function where a user can request a project. The request has 2 fields for other employees to be added.

It's got a field for a person who is responsible for the project (`person_responsible`) and the employee who is supposed to attend the opening meeting (`person_attending`).

What I want to know is, since both these fields (`person_responsible` and `person_attending`) will be pulling it's data from `hr_employees` table, how would I set this up in my `Project`-Model.

At the moment I have the one field set up like this:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'HrEmployee' => array(
        'className' => 'HrEmployee',
        'foreignKey' => 'responsible_person',
        'fields' => 'HrEmployee.employeename',
    )
);
```

How would I set up the other field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do in this cases is to make two associations. Since cake allow to customize relations, you can have two relations to the same model with different names.

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'ResponsibleEmployee' => array(
        'className' => 'HrEmployee',
        'foreignKey' => 'responsible_person',
        'fields' => 'HrEmployee.employeename',
    ),
    'AttendingEmployee' => array(
        'className' => 'HrEmployee',
        'foreignKey' => 'person_attending',
        'fields' => 'HrEmployee.employeename',
    )
);
```

Change the names to adjust your needs. Now, if your model is set as containable and you retrieve the Project model with those models in it, you'll get something like

```
array('Project' => array(/*data project*/),
      'ResponsibleEmployee' => array(/*name*/),
      'AttendingEmployee' => array(/*name*/)
)
```

(or another variation of that array depending on how the query was made).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this but I receive an `unknown column`-error. But the column is there.

Comment: `HrEmployee.employeename`, but I know it exists in my `HrEmployee` table

Comment: try removing the `HrEmployee` (leaving `'fields' => 'employeename'` instead)

Comment: Awesome. That works. It didn't work because `employeename` is a virtual field. I assumed that a virtual field is similar to a normal field in the table.